# Adding css files in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to add css files in spring mvc project.I am using myeclipse.

I am adding `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />` in **`spring-servlet.xml`**

When i am going to run i am getting exception

exception

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]
>   Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:59)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.findParserForElement(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:84)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:136)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>       org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>       org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
>       org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>       org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
>       org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

My **`spring-servlet.xml`** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" /> 
 <context:component-scan  base-package="com.arobol.controller" /> 
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: can you add your spring-servlet.xml, and which spring mvc version are you using?

Comment: Yea i am adding spring-servlet.xml and using spring 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the xml schema of you xml file is corresponding to your spring version, so for spring 3.0 should be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

the stacktrace issue saying

```
Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources] Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
```

appears as though you're having a mistmatch between your jars and the included schema

UPDATE

Better yet, include the XSDs without the version, that will match the schema's with the schemas you're using in your app. So something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

Comment: I have replace this code but now it showing red cross in spring-servlet.xml and showing error no declaration can be found for element <mvc:resources

Comment: can you add your original spring-servlet.xml to the question

Comment: I have add my spring-servlet.xml in my question

Comment: the issue is as I suspected, you have the spring-mvc-3.1.xsd while it should be spring-mvc-3.0.xsd. Try changing only that in your original file.

Comment: I am going to change spring-mvc-3.1.xsd  to spring-mvc-3.0.xsd it showing red cross in spring-servlet.xml and showing error no declaration can be found for element <mvc:resources

Comment: as an additional, and I've updated in an answer, you can leave out the version numbers from XSD, it will match the XSDs found in your jars. If in this case your error persist, it would mean that the version of your jars is not able to support the conf. Let me know how it turns out

Comment: than you'll likely using a spring-webmvc jar less than 3.0, can you check in your project, and paste in the question the version of your spring-webmvc jar

Comment: On a different note are you sure you dont have multiple versions of the same spring-webmvc.jar in your project's classpath?

Comment: I am using spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Master Slave is right, to solve this you need to: 1) make sure that you have only one spring version on classpath and 2) use version-less XSDs in your XML configuration.

Comment: I am using spring 3 and only one spring version on classpath.And use spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar as jar files and use spring-mvc-3.1.xsd in xml

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are getting error after adding `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />`

Try removing `<mvc:`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" /> 
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.arobol.controller" /> 
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
</bean>
</beans>
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


  <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>

    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.arobol.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean> 
  </beans>
```

After calling controller exception occur.

Comment: beans:beans is not found error in spring-servlet.xml

Comment: use beans:bean instead

Comment: Till now same problem occur.

Comment: You only allowed to map a directory to all your webpage only. So use `<resources mapping="/**" location="/" />` then at your .jsp add `<style><%@include file="pathtoyour/css/yourcss.css"%></style>`